# Textures for city facade design such as roofs and walls?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have used textures from services such as [FreeImages.com](http://www.freeimages.com) (formerly sxc.hu) and different bundles but is rarity that they connect well together. This print design resulted in odd lines and some bad textures where the images do not connect well together. My friend suggested blurring and I think it could work with the best textures but not with poorer ones. So how should I design this kind of textures? Some good sources and which method to use with poorer textures for large city facade designs?

[image]

**Update**

> *Use Photoshop and put each vertical texture to independent file so the file size does not increase too fast, easier to manage.*

In Photoshop, I used the finger, perspective projection, rotation -- to create dark textures for a tall building from this [texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRqmk.jpg). Now if you look at the general trend in the black-white picture, you can see that certain patterns are too repeating [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6rhI.png). It is very rough and time-consuming to use orthogonal textures with convex fix and then adapt it to the environment. For an arbitrary-sized building how to automate the creation of unique tiles? Basically the problem would require to build a convex lattice against which to apply the texture with light coming from the floor level when the texture rises up like a tower. How can you do it? With some 3D software that could extract the light-adjusted texture?

Comment: Why Indesign for textures? That seems so counter-intuitive.

Comment: This might be of interest; take a look at the pattern tools. If not perfect for your task, than it might give some useful ideas: http://www.colourlovers.com/pattern/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Photoshop. You should never blur the image it will just make it look bad.

Use the Offset filter Filter>other>offset to nudge the image so that the edge of the tiling is in the editable area. From there you need to paint/clone out the seams before using the offset filter again to return the image back to its original position.

Example of an image after I used the offset filter:

[image]

Comment: an extra note: while painting out the seam, do not alter the outer edges of the texture, otherwise you will create new seams.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to somehow specify the light source for example to come from bottom, is there some filter to adjust the light like with some 3D software?

Comment: if you were to do that, it would no longer be tilable vertically, unless you are talking about per-brick highlights. If you are talking per-brick, you could probably get the effect by messing around with selections and applying filters to highlight/shadow different areas.